# Back button leading to paginated view in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a Paginated view of a content list. Let's call it the Teaser list. Each member's fields have 'Link' set to Content in the view's field settings. On the page for that piece of content (let's call it the Full view) I'd like to have a back button that goes back to the specific paginated point of the page with the Teaser list.
In other words, if I have the teaser list on /pagename?page=2 (third paginated page) and I click on an item, when I go to the Full view for that item, I want to have a back button go back to /pagename?page=2, not /pagename.
How can I accomplish this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, for lack of anything better. I used window.history.back() on the back button.